Isomorphism of real vector spaces $\Omega^1(\mathfrak u(n)) \cong \Omega^{0,1}(\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb C))$
Consider a compact Riemann surface $X$. In [1, p. 570] the isomorphism of real vector spaces
$$
\Omega^1_{\mathbb R}(X,\mathfrak u(n)) \cong \Omega^{0,1}(X,\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb C))
$$
is mentioned. What is this isomorphism, where does it come from?
I know that, as real vector bundles $TX \cong T^{0,1}X$ but I am unsure about the map between sections of $\mathfrak u(n)$ and $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb C)$.
Edit: Thanks to the comment from Qiaochu Yuan I stumbled on this question which seems to answer my question!
[1] Atiyah, Bott. The Yang-Mills equations over Riemann surfaces. 1982

It just comes from the fact that $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the complexification of $\mathfrak{u}(n)$; as far as I can tell nothing else is being used here.
